# Copy multiple files from different directories while renaming?

Tags: rename, for

I have several files to copy from various directories but each file has the same name so I need to copy them to a single directory and rename each in turn as "expect1, expect2, expect3", etc.
The code I've tried so far is

```
     let i=1; for file in delay* ; do (
     cd $file
     cp expectation_file ~/target_dir
     cd ~/target_dir/
     mv expectation_file expect{i}
     ((i++)) );
     done
```

But this just makes every file called "expect1". Can someone help out? I think it's the counting loop that's wrong but can't figure it out. Thanks!

EDIT: Made a mistake in code there. Had 1=1 instead of i=1 and then ++i not i++.

Comment: Even though I don't know this language, I'm pretty sure you should move `((++i))` outside of the parenthesis block:  `); ((++i));`

Comment: in `mv expectation_file expect{i}`  the `i` is missing a `$`

Comment: Actually taking `((i++))` out of parenthesis seemed to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be more versatile.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
source_files=$(find /tmp -name "*.zip")
target_dir=~/temp1/
for source in ${source_files}; do
  ((i++))
  mv ${source} ${target_dir}/$(basename ${source})${i}
done
```

source_files expression can be anything like $(ls *.zip), this example finds all zip files under /tmp/.